# VBA Function that returns the number of the month

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a VBA function that returns the number of a month with cell referencing. I want to call the function CheckMonth

For instance, if I have 01/01/2019 (dd/mm/yyyy) as a date than I want to return it as a integer ( in this case, 01)

or for 04/06/2019 ( returns 06)
       12/09/2019 ( returns 09) and so on

```
 Function CheckMonth () As integer

  Mid(Range("Active.cell"), 4, 2)
```

I know that I need to use this Mid(range( x ,4,2)) but not sure how to implement it.

Please could you advise on how I can do this?

Comment: Can you just use `Month(A1)` and be done with it? It works as a formula in the front end as a method in VBA.

Comment: Are you trying to code the [Month function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function) yourself? If so, you should state that in your question.

Comment: @JNevill Thank you, but I was trying to see how to code it as I am a beginner

Comment: @Nacorid You are right, I ll mention it next time when I have questions.

Comment: @DavidGorgan That makes sense! GarysStudent came through for you with a solid answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need VBA, then consider:

```
Function CheckMonth(r As Range) As Integer
    CheckMonth = Month(r.Value)
End Function
```

It will return the month number regardless of the date formatting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per previous comments, you can use Month function. You also need to add Excel.Range argument:

```
Function CheckMonth(rngCell As Excel.Range) As Integer
    CheckMonth = Month(rngCell.Value)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

From a learning perspective, perhaps a few options will allow you to get a better understanding of the various tools available:

```
Public Function CheckMonth(r As Range) As String
    ' Find month number and then format that to double-digit string
    CheckMonth = Format(Month(r.Value), "00")
End Function

Public Function CheckMonth2(r As Range) As String
    ' Format the date to 'mm' - i.e. just the month element
    CheckMonth2 = Format(r.Value, "mm")
End Function

Public Function CheckMonth3(r As Range) As String
    ' Format the date to a standard string and extract the middle element
    CheckMonth3 = Mid(Format(r.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy"), 4, 2)
End Function

Public Function CheckMonth4(r As Range) As String
    ' Concatenate a zero with the month number, then take last 2 characters
    CheckMonth4 = Right("0" & Month(r.Value), 2)
End Function
```